# If php $_SESSION variable has data

Tags: php, session, session-variables

I am new to php. I am trying to check if the session variable has a value? If yes do nothing else set value. This is my code:

```php
if (isset($_POST['ProductName'])) {
    if (!empty($_SESSION['UserBasketID'])) {
        $order = $_POST['ProductName'];
        $date = date("Ymd");
        $_SESSION['UserBasketID'] = $date.$order;
        var_dump($_SESSION['UserBasketID']);            
    } else {
        echo 'The session is set';
        if (isset($_SESSION['UserBasketID'])) {
            var_dump($_SESSION['UserBasketID']);
        }
    }
}
```

And can somebody tell me how it works in php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [php documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.session-start.php) states that since 7.1.0:

> session_start() now returns FALSE and no longer initializes $_SESSION when it failed to start the session.

So the correct way to check if the session property is set will now be:

```php
if (session_start() && isset($_SESSION['UserBasketID'])) {
   // $_SESSION['UserBasketID'] is set
} else {
   // Either no session, $_SESSION not initialized or $_SESSION['UserBasketID'] not set
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your if-condition is backwards.

`empty()` returns true if the variable in not set or if it contains an empty value.
`!empty()` (with the `!` in front of it) returns true if the variable *is* set and doesn't contain an empty value.

So the code:

```
if (!empty($_SESSION['UserBasketID']))
```

will evaluate as `true` if the session is defined and has a non-empty value, which means that you're currently only setting the session if it's already set.

Remove the `!` in front of `empty()` and it should work:

```
if (isset($_POST['ProductName'])) {
    if (empty($_SESSION['UserBasketID'])) {
        $order = $_POST['ProductName'];
        $date  = date("Ymd");
        $_SESSION['UserBasketID'] = $date . $order;
        var_dump($_SESSION['UserBasketID']);            
    } else {
        echo 'The session is set';

        // We can remove the if-statement here since we
        // we've already checked it
        var_dump($_SESSION['UserBasketID']);
    }
}
```

Comment: I just try out it and it rewrite my session variable by clicking on another item. Är du svensk?

Comment: @AndeasWalz - That's a totally different issue though. If this solves that specific issue in your question, you should accept it. If you got some other issue, then you should write a new question where you include a proper explanation and all the relevant code. And yes, jag är svensk :-)